# PHP Convert RGB Array to String variable

Tags: php

I am converting a Hexcode into RGB and when I echo this is outputs correctly EG, 55,55,55
. I am wanting to assign this RGB Value to a variable called RGBColour but it is just assigning the wordd 'array' to the variable. Can someone please give me a pointer as to what I am doing wrong.

```
$hexcolour = $_POST['hexcolour'];
$RGBcolour = list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($charitycolour1, "#%02x%02x%02x"));
```

Comment: Sounds like `$RGBcolour` is an array. Try `var_dump($RBGcolour);` to see what it contains.

Comment: The code you're showing here will give a syntax error.

Comment: If it outputs a "55, 55, 55" string, you should use the split method like so: `$RGBcolor = list($r, $g, $b) = split(",", "55,55,55")`.

Comment: The given code does not define the variable `$charitycolour1` after all. What have you tried to spot the problem in your real code?

Answer (score 2):

RGBcolour is an array as the var_dump shows, but then you can get the rgb color again with a `sprintf`:

```
$charitycolour1 = '#ff3300';
$RGBcolour = list($r, $g, $b) = sscanf($charitycolour1, "#%02x%02x%02x");
var_dump($RGBcolour);


$RGBcolour = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $r, $g, $b);
echo 'RGBcolour: '.$RGBcolour;
```

outputs

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(255)
  [1]=>
  int(51)
  [2]=>
  int(0)
}
RGBcolour: #ff3300
```

If you want the RGB as `255,51,0` you can use `join`:

```
$charitycolour1 = '#ff3300';
$RGBarray = sscanf($charitycolour1, "#%02x%02x%02x");
$RGBcolour = join(',', $RGBarray);
echo 'RGBcolour: '.$RGBcolour;
```

This outputs: `RGBcolour: 255,51,0`

And if later on you want the hexa value again from that `255,51,0` value:

```
$RGBcolour = '255,51,0';
$RGBarray = explode(',', $RGBcolour);
$hexaColour = sprintf("#%02x%02x%02x", $RGBarray[0], $RGBarray[1], $RGBarray[2]);
echo 'Hexa Colour: '.$hexaColour;
```

that outputs: `Hexa Colour: #ff3300`

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the below but it just sets the Hex code as the value of $RGBcolour and not the R,G,B, value. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks so if the hex code was #ff3300 I was to be able to set $RGBcolour to 255,51,0 for its RGB value.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. If I want to post this value to a db, can I do so just referencing $RGBcolour ?

Comment: Exactly, now it's a string. Well, but keep in mind that when you work in a db it's a good practice to use **prepared statements** to prevent from SQL injection attacks. Don't just concatenate strings.

Comment: By the way, if you then restore that value from a database you'll need to split it (the oposite of the `join` to get the array again from the string) and then use the `sprintf` expression I used before to get it's original value in hexa

Comment: It would be great if you could mark the answer as correct if you consider it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to output the RGB value as three separate variables. Eg $R1, $G1, $B1?

Comment: Yes, now I don't have a computer near but with `explode` (to get an array) and `list` (to get each part) is not difficult

Comment: Thank you, you have been amazing